# How do I fill "partial diagonal axis" of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `A` of three dimensions. I want to have

```
A[i, i, :] = 1.0
```

for every `i`.

How can I do this elegantly in numpy? Is it possible to avoid all `for` loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1** You can create a diagonal mask with [`np.eye`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html) and then use boolean-indexing to assign -

```
mask = np.eye(A.shape[0], dtype=bool)
A[mask] = 1.0
```

**Approach #2** Using integer based indexing -

```
r = np.arange(A.shape[0])
A[r,r] = 1.0
```

**Approach #3** Reshape into `2D` and then assign into rows -

```
n = A.shape[0]
A.reshape(-1,A.shape[-1])[np.arange(n)*(n+1)] = 1.0
```

Comment: It does work. But how to understand it? The doc says "mask" index arrays returns a copy of data, not a view. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: @ChongWang We are not extracting data with the mask, we are assigning. So,it's fine here.

Comment: @ChongWang In this [**section**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) , look at the last line. It talks about extracting a *piece* out off the input array. Let's say I do : `y = x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])]`. `y` won't be a view there and any later changes made to `y` would not affect `x`. But with assigning, it makes temporary array and then assigns back (read those last lines in the link again). I am guessing the same behavior is repeated for boolean-indexing.